# Javascript object literal: value initialization?

Tags: javascript, constructor, object-literal

i was using object literal to create an object with methods.
Here a simple example.

```
var SizeManager = {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    ratio : this.width / this.height,
    resize : function (newWidth) {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newWidth / ratio;
    }
}
```

My issue is that SizeManager.ratio returns "**NaN**". I'm quite sure it's an initialization issue.
Is there a way to obtain a correct ratio value?
Is there a way to assign a costructor or initializer to an object literal?
Is defining a constructor objcet the only way?

EDIT: off course SizeManager is ideally a singleton (only one object), that's way i was using object literal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's an initialization issue. `this` does not refer to your `SizeManager` object at the point you're using it. (Object initializers don't change the value of `this`.) `this` is set by how you call a function and has the same value throughout that function call. You're not *calling* any function there, so `this` has whatever value it had prior to the beginning of that code.

(I've pointed out something about `ratio` from your specific example at the very end of this, but first let's walk through a few options for the general case you raise.)

[Daniel's given you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770169/javascript-object-literal-value-initialization/3770207#3770207) a good steer on making `ratio` a function except he doesn't seem to have realized that you want to vary the width. Alternately, if `width` and `height` aren't going to change, just calculate it afterward:

```
var SizeManager = {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    resize : function (newWidth) {
        this.width = newWidth;
        this.height = newWidth / this.ratio;
    }
};
SizeManager.ratio = SizeManager.width / SizeManager.height;
```

(Side note: I've added `this.` to the properties you're referencing in `resize`. They were missing from your original, but they're required. Without them, you're dealing with the [horror of implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which is a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>.)

Of course, you might encapsulate all of that into a factory:

```
function makeSizeManager(width, height) {
    return {
        width : width,
        height : height,
        ratio : width / height,
        resize : function (newWidth) {
            this.width = newWidth;
            this.height = newWidth / this.ratio;
        }
    };
}
var SizeManager = makeSizeManager(800, 600);
```

...but then you might as well make it an actual constructor function so you don't create lots of duplicate (but identical) `resize` functions:

```
function SizeManager(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.ratio = width / height;
}
SizeManager.prototype.resize = function (newWidth) {
    this.width = newWidth;
    this.height = newWidth / this.ratio;
};
var aSizeManagerInstance = new SizeManager(800, 600);
```

(Note I changed the names a bit on this last one.)

And as one last final note: In your specific example, you don't actually need to store `ratio` at all, you could do this:

```
var SizeManager = {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    resize : function (newWidth) {
        var ratio = this.width / this.height;
        this.width = newWidth;
        this.height = newWidth / ratio;
    }
};
```

But that's just for that specific example, hence the discussion above to talk about the general case.

Comment: If you're changing it from an object literal to a function, you need to change the way you specify properties (in the third block of code). ie. `this.width = width` instead of `this.width: width`

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks! looks like I only half-edited those lines after pasting. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Your `ratio` property should actually be a method if you want it to change based on changes to `width` and `height`:

```
var SizeManager = {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    ratio : function() {
      return this.width / this.height;
    },
    resize : function (newWidth) {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newWidth / ratio;
    }
}
```

Also, you probably want to refer to `this.width` and `this.height` instead of `width` and `height` in the `resize` method.

Comment: In resize function, `ratio` needs to be changed to `this.ratio()`

Comment: So ratio must be changed to a method and can not be a property. Right?

Comment: @Josh I didn't change the resize method, I'll leave that to the OP. It'd probably be best to cache the old ratio before changing the width in it though, because with `ratio` being a function, the value will change after `this.width` is changed.

Comment: @bonfo if `ratio` isn't a method, the value will never change (unless you explicitly reset `SizeManager.ratio = ...`), so unless you want the ratio fixed at 800/600, it should be a method.

Answer (score 0):

In an object literal, `this` only refers to the object literal itself when it is inside a function. You can try something like this instead of an object literal; `this` will refer to the object you are creating both inside and outside of functions.

```
var SizeManager = new function(){
    this.width = 800;
    this.height = 600;
    this.ratio = this.width / this.height;
    this.resize = function (newWidth) {
        this.width = newWidth;
        this.height = newWidth / this.ratio;
    }
}
```

That will work for a singleton pattern. If you need more than one SizeManager, make it a constructor function instead of an object.

```
function SizeManager (w, h){
  w && (this.width=w);
  h && (this.height=h);
  this.ratio = this.width / this.height;
}
SizeManager.prototype={ 
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  resize: function (newWidth) {
    this.width = newWidth;
    this.height = newWidth / this.ratio;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"In the object literal, `this` only refers to the object literal itself when it is inside a function."* There is no object literal **at all** in your code snippet. There's a constructor function, which you're calling immediately via `new`, but there's no object literal. Inside the constructor function, `this` refers to the new object created by `new` as part of calling the function.

Comment: After calling `resize`, the `ratio` will be inaccurate

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I was talking about the object literal in his code, not mine, obviously, as mine doesn't contain one, as you point out. Context, man.

Comment: @no: I *think* I see what you mean, but frankly I'd reword it. I know this stuff pretty well, but still thought you were talking about your code, not his.

Comment: JS standards at my company prohibit the "w && this.width = 5", it's not very easy to understand.

Comment: @Juan Mendes - As for being easy to understand, it should make perfect sense if logical operator short-circuiting is understood, which should not be too much to expect from a javascript programmer. Lots of js code relies on short-circuiting; you see stuff like this all the time: `if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz) { alert(foo.bar.baz) }` ... so why not just write `foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz && alert(foo.bar.baz)`?

Comment: For the same reason you don't use a table for layout, the original intended semantics. The && operator in js is meant to compare two objects and return the one with the true value (0 || 5 returns 5). But to be very honest, if we had a vote and most developers agreed, I wouldn't mind it, but I would vote against it. I actually do like to use it for null checks as you suggest, but not when it can cause a method to be called based on short circuiting. Something like if (a && a.prop) {} is ok in my eyes.